# Append new Pandas DataFrame to an old one without column names sorted

Tags: python, pandas

I append a new dataframe to an old one:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series
from pandas import DataFrame

df1 = DataFrame(np.arange(3.).reshape((1, 3)), columns=list('dcb'), index=['Ohio'])
df2 = DataFrame(np.arange(3.).reshape((1, 3)), columns=list('bdc'), index=['Utah'])
print df1
print df2
print pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

then i got result like this:

```
       d    c    b
Ohio  0.0  1.0  2.0

       b    d    c
Utah  0.0  1.0  2.0

       b    c    d
Ohio  2.0  1.0  0.0
Utah  0.0  2.0  1.0
```

however i want the columns in the result not sorted as 'bcd' but as origin 'dcb' like:

```
       d    c    b
Ohio  0.0  1.0  2.0
Utah  1.0  2.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `join_axes` argument:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], join_axes=[df1.columns])
```

Comment: For this case, you can also do `pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)`, which will be default in a future version.

Comment: I get `TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'join_axes'`. No luck with `sort=False` either...

Answer (score 2):

You can store the original order in a variable and then reapply it after combining:

```
df1 = DataFrame(np.arange(3.).reshape((1, 3)), columns=list('dcb'), index=['Ohio'])
orig_column_order = df1.columns
df2 = DataFrame(np.arange(3.).reshape((1, 3)), columns=list('bdc'), index=['Utah'])
combined = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=list('dbc'))
combined = combined[orig_column_order]
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(combined)
```

Gives:

```
        d    c    b
Ohio  0.0  1.0  2.0
        b    d    c
Utah  0.0  1.0  2.0
          d    c    b
d Ohio  0.0  1.0  2.0
b Utah  1.0  2.0  0.0
```

Comment: @HYRY's  answer is more concise. but thank you! it really works!

Comment: And I'm sorry for the mistake in my question. I thought I have deleted 'keys=list('dbc')' in the last line, but it turns out just now that I left it as 'print pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=list('dbc')) ' as it was. Sorry for causing the confusion.